# How to link database information into a bootstrap table using XAMPP?

Tags: php, database, twitter-bootstrap

I seem to be doing something wrong with my table, as I get the error:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap-3.2.0\docs\list.php on line 44
>
> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

when I try loading my page. The PHP is fairly basic:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("drinkdealz") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friday") or die(mysql_error());


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Print out the contents of the entry 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Date'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Admission'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Performer'] . '</td>';
}
?>
```

The database is called "Drinkdealz" and the table is called Friday.

Comment: is your mysql started from xampp control?

Comment: Are you sure MySQL is running? It may not have started up. Or perhaps it is running on a non-standard port? If so you will need to specify that in your connection string.

Comment: (Aside: "friday" is an odd name for a table. It would be better for this to be called "performances" or "events", and then a column to be added to indicate that the data within is related to Fridays (Friday performances)).

Comment: Hi, Yeah MYSQL and Apache are currently running but it says 19:19:46  [main]  You are not running with administrator rights! Could that affect it? And yeah friday is an odd name, i intend on changing it!

Comment: it's running from port 3306